# Manage JPA Entity with Set data structure - using add method

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpa-2.0

I see examples where  HashSet used in entity, and is treated like other data types. But I am looking to use "add" instead of set whole object

```
package com.baeldung.manytomany.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "course_like", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    private Set<Course> likedCourses = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<CourseRating> ratings = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<CourseRegistration> registrations = new HashSet<>();

    // additional properties

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Course> getLikedCourses() {
        return likedCourses;
    }

    public void setLikedCourses(Set<Course> likedCourses) {
        this.likedCourses = likedCourses;
    }

    public Set<CourseRating> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(Set<CourseRating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public Set<CourseRegistration> getRegistrations() {
        return registrations;
    }

    public void setRegistrations(Set<CourseRegistration> registrations) {
        this.registrations = registrations;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Is there a better approach than

> ```
> public Set<CourseRating> getRatings() {
>     return ratings;
> }
>
> public void setRatings(Set<CourseRating> ratings) {
>     this.ratings = ratings;
> }
> ```

I did try

> public void addRatings(CourseRating rating) {
> this.ratings.add(rating);   }

but object is not persisting. I thought save of student should take care of saving rating. What am I missing ?

Comment: After you invoke `addRatings` method, do you only call the save for the Student object? If yes, you might want to use `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` (or ALL) on your `ratings` field

Comment: I did follow this - https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/  need to see any other problems. we need to do more than cascade, like reverse linking child to parent,  and other as mentioned in answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok sorted
(1)

```
     public void addRatings(CourseRating rating) {
     this.ratings.add(rating); rating.setBlah(this); 
 }
```

(2) Updated Entity:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "exam", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("id")
private Set<CourseRating> ratings = new HashSet<>();
```

Was using Embeddable, so was getting error  - null id generated for:class ... so setting id from available objects

```
ratings.setId(new ThatKey(some1, some2));
```